# Operator in C/C++

Tags: c++

I've faced lines of code

```
int a=6, b=7;
cout << (b,a);
```

it prompt out 16.
What is (b,a) mean? Does it do a operation?

Comment: That should print out `6`.

Comment: The "1" must be from something else before.. it should output 6

Comment: "it prompt 16" - [no, it doesn't](http://ideone.com/ASd7nt)

Comment: Show the previous cout.

Comment: The title suggests you know the comma being an operator here. So... why not have a look? E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression

```
(b,a)
```

there is the comma operator. Its value is the value of the last (right) subexpression after the comma. The value of the first (left) subexpression is discarded. So the output will be

```
6
```

From the C++ Standard

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;
>   the left expression is a discardedvalue expression (Clause 5).87 Every
>   value computation and side effect associated with the left expression
>   is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated
>   with the right expression. The type and value of the result are the
>   type and value of the right operand; the result is of the same value
>   category as its right operand, and is a bit-field if its right operand
>   is a glvalue and a bit-field. If the value of the right operand is a
>   temporary (12.2), the result is that temporary.